# Show that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L_{\infty}$ if and only if $\{f_n\} \rightarrow f$ uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measurable space, show that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L_{\infty}$ if and only if $\{f_n\} \rightarrow f$  uniformly.

I proved $\Rightarrow) $ but in the other direction i have problems i try to use:
$$ \mathrm{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty} || f_n - f||_{\infty} = 0 
 \Leftrightarrow \forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists N: n > N \Rightarrow |f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq || f_n - f||_{\infty} < \varepsilon$$ $\mu$-almost everywhere on $X$.

But i not see how use aplicated, maybe is a conceptual problem.

Any hint or help i will be very grateful

Comment: The sets $E_n=\{|f_n|>\|f_n\|\}$ are negligible, and so is $E=\bigcup_nE_n$. Thus, w.l.o generality (remove the set $E$ from the space), one may assume that $|f_n(x)|\leq\|f_n\|_\infty$ for all $n$ and $x\in X$. Then $L_\infty$ convergence is indeed uniform convergence.

Comment: Presumably, "uniformly" in the problem statement was intended to be "uniformly almost everywhere."